# "support files should use exactly same version" Android studio error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-support-library

I have following dependencies in my app-level `build.gradle` file

```
dependencies {
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.0.2'
}
```

These works fine without any error. But, When I try to put a new third party dependency of CircleImageView `implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'`, the gradle build fails and there is error on `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.0.2'` line saying `All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version...`. I am wondering how this third party library creating problem in support libraries. What is wrong there?

Comment: Use this `implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'`

Comment: @NileshRathod still there is an error

Comment: Because that third party library internally also uses the app compat library and because the version used by your project is different from the library version, it gives the error. But your app should work fine even with the error.

Comment: Also update dependencies for cardview  `implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'`

Comment: @NileshRathod Thanks, worked fine!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [All com.android.support libraries must use the exact same version specification](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42374151/all-com-android-support-libraries-must-use-the-exact-same-version-specification)

Answer (score 2):

That library is implementing support libraries as well, but different versions. Specifically, it uses the `support-annotations` 27.1.0 library.

There are two things you can do.

1. Update your dependencies. 27.0.2 is outdated. 27.1.0 is as well, but less so.
2. Exclude that library from your implementation and implement it yourself:

   ```
   implementation ("de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0") {
       exclude group: "com.android.support" module: "support-annotations"
   }
   implementation 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.1.1'
   ```

   You should update all your support dependencies to 27.1.1.

Answer (score 1):

The third party library internally uses the app compat library and because the version used by project is different from the library version, it gives the error. Updating `appcompat`, `design` and `cardview` dependencies to version `27.1.1` worked fine as follows.

```
dependencies {
  implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
  implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'
  implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.1'
  androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.1'
  implementation 'com.android.volley:volley:1.1.1'
  implementation 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:4.8.0'
  implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
  implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.2.0'
}
```

Comment: [It’s OK to Ask and Answer Your Own Questions](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: @Mohsen I have to wait 2 days for accepting my own answer

Comment: Seems this is what TheWanderer told you in his answer. Answering your own question should be reserved for questions that have no duplicates on SO and for new information not to state which advice you followed

Answer (score 0):

The support libraries should have the same version as the other dependencies which are related.

Change them to v `27.1.1` (The point is they should have the same version):

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
implementation 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:27.1.1'
```

And then if you saw any errors which points to "should have same version", run :

```
./gradlew dependencies
```

To see which library is using old version.

Mostly, it can be fixed by adding the updated version of the library (same as the support library) in your `build.gradle` dependencies.

Comment: Why 28? The library uses 27.1.1 and OP uses 27.0.2, which means their compile and target SDK are set to 27. This would cause more problems. And `support-media-compat` has nothing to do with CircleImageView.

Comment: They _should_ use the same version. Using 28.0.0 means they _aren't_.

Answer (score 0):

If you want all support libraries including third party libraries internally use the same support library version, then add below code in your project level `gradle`

```
ext {
    support_library_version = '27.1.1'
}

subprojects {
    project.configurations.all {
        resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->

            if (details.requested.group == 'com.android.support'
                    && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex')) {
                details.useVersion "$support_library_version"
            }
        }
    }
}
```